# net card not installed

Tags: centos, centos5

i have many times try to install nic drivers but it is showing one error

check old drivers and unload it.

```
build the module and install
make:***/lib/modules/2.6.18.e15xen/build: no such file or directory.stop
make [1]:*** [modules] Error2
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

pls send the answer my question , i amwaiting for u r message,, pls help me

Answer (score 0):

You need install kernel source packages:

```
# yum install kernel-xen-devel
```